# Wordpress header image gets wider

Tags: wordpress, header

I'm beginner and trying to change the header image of my site. It has been written in my settings that the image size must be 1600px*400px. But when I choose the image (With the same size), it gets wider. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you post link to your site? hard to troubleshoot without it. This could be fixed with a simple CSS I guess.

Comment: Actually it's already under the local host (XAMPP).